# Flutter use context when handling dynamic link from app closed

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I see this weird behaviour when handling dynamic links. What I want to do is that when coming from a link containing matchId parameter I want to clean up the navigation stack, put up the `AvailableMatches` page and after the `MatchDetails` page and finally show a modal. This is the code I use in the link handler

```
  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
    onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
        final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
        if (deepLink != null) {
           handleLink(deepLink);
        }); 

  Future<void> handleLink(Uri deepLink) async {
      var context = navigatorKey.currentContext;
      var matchId = deepLink.queryParameters["match_id"];
   
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
         AvailableMatches.routeName,
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false
      );
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(MatchDetails.routeName,
         arguments: ScreenArguments(
            matchId, false)
      );
      await showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => Text("done"));
  }
```

If the app is already open this works fine. If the app is starting from this link I have the following `initState` in the first `StatefulWidget`

```
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initDynamicLinks();
        loadData(context);
      }
      
      Future<void> loadData(BuildContext context) async {
          final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
          handleLink(data.link);
      }
```

In this case the `handeLink` method works until the latest model. The pages are pushed correctly on the stack however the last model doesn't show up.

I am adding prints and things like that but it seems that this line never gets executed. There is no crash or exception. It just gets ignored